# Prevent document opening when creating new document

Tags: new-document

I created a document library and customized the New Word document template. I need to prevent SharePoint Online to automatically open the newly created document when I press "New" button. I want to open it manually because I need to set some columns value (to which I refer into the document) before opening the document. Is it possible to stop automatic opening of newly created documents?

Thank you.